# Select sub columns from a view

Tags: sql-server, select, view

I have a large view in Sql Server named ViewA which looks like

```
Select
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB,
  ...
  ColumnZ
FROM TableA
Join TableB ON 
...
Join TableZ ON
```

This view gives me exactly what I need in some cases. However in other cases I only need one or two columns and only a few rows so I am doing something like

```
Select Top 5
  ColumnA,
  ColumnB
FROM ViewA
Where Condition
```

This top 5 query runs very slow and I suspect that SQL Server is building the full result set for all the view columns and not just for ColumnA and ColumnB

If I change the view to just return Top 5 and ColumnA and ColumnB then it is much faster.

Does SQL Server not optimize in this case if I am only selecting a few rows or columns from the larger set?

Comment: Are you saying that if you remove the `WHERE` condition, the result is faster?  That seems to indicate the predicate condition is your problem.  Have you tried running a `SELECT *` to return the top 5 from all columns, but without the `WHERE` condition?  What are your results then?

Comment: No keep the where condition but limit the columns. Seems Select top X (subset columns) from ViewA is slower than changing the view to return exactly what I want.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused, because a view is just a non-materialized projection of data in a database.  So, from your given `ViewA`, if you run `SELECT Top X (column_subset) FROM ViewA WHERE condition`, I would think it would be identical to the situation where you made a new view `ViewA_reduced` which only contained your desired columns, and then ran `SELECT Top X * FROM ViewA_reduced WHERE condition`.  Have you tried running `EXPLAIN` to see where the differences are in the query plan?

Comment: It appears it may be related to doing an order by on the view results. If I execute the SQL directly very fast. If I use an order by on the view then very slow.

Comment: Do you have an index built on the column which you are trying to order by?

Comment: Yes it is the Primary Key.

Comment: Provide the `view` definition, the actual query and the execution plan of the problematic query. The question is unanswerable as it is.